# Execute cal function in linux given month and year

Tags: unix

I am writing a bash script for a beginning unix/linux class that has the user input the month and year that they want to view. I am not sure how to execute the calendar given the user input.

Here is what I have.

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo -n "Enter the month you wish displayed: "; read month  
echo -n "Enter the year you wish displayed: "; read year  
echo cal '$month' '$year'
```

Comment: Just `cal $month $year` should be enough, without `echo` neither `'` wrapping variables.

Comment: The `'` prevents the shell from expanding the variable (`$`). Take them out. Also - you want to RUN `cal`, not `echo` it. So `cal $month $year` is all it takes.

Comment: A terminology quibble: `cal` is a command, not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `echo`, the rest of the line (after possible processing by the shell) gets output to `stdout` (or possibly piped into the next process). This prevents `cal` from being treated as a command.

There are different kinds of quotation marks that are used in 'nix: the `"` double quote, and the `'` single quote. There's also the ` backtick. Each has a very specific use.

Any command surrounded by backticks is *expanded inline* - that is, it is executed and the output is put in the line. Thus,

```
echo hello `whoami`
```

will result in `hello john` if your user name (the response to the `whoami` command) is `john`.

The single quote has the opposite effect: it "protects" any text from the shell, so no further attempts will be made to process. Thus

```
echo hello '`whoami`'
```

will result in

```
hello '`whoami`'
```

The double quote `"` is a bit less restrictive. The `$` (variable), `\` (escape), and ` backtick are still interpreted, but it's a good way to pass an argument with a space in it to a script.  Thus

```
doSomething for me
```

passes two parameters to the function `doSomething`: `for`, and `me`. On the other hand

```
doSomething "for me"
```

only passes a single parameter, `for me`

I hope this clarifies things for you.